# Simple chat room

Tags: java, object-oriented, chat

I'm writing this simple chat room in Java, and I wish to refactor a couple of things, like the following `switch` statement that should be replaced with polymorphism or at least not rely on another class enum.

Message Object:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
    public enum MessageTypes {PUBLIC_MESSAGE,PTIVATE_MASSAGE,USER_DUPLICATE,USER_LOGOUT,SERVER_LOGOUT,USERSLIST}; 
    private String dest;
    private String src;
    private String messageContent;
    private MessageTypes type;


    public Message(String source) {
        src = source; 
    }

    public Message(String source,String message) {
        this(source);
        messageContent = message;
        type = MessageTypes.PUBLIC_MESSAGE;
    }

    public Message(String source,String destination,String message) {
        this(source);
        messageContent = message;
        dest= destination;
        type = MessageTypes.PTIVATE_MASSAGE;
    }

    public String getDest() {
        return dest;
    }
    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }
    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }
    public MessageTypes getType() {
        return type;
    }

    private void setType(MessageTypes typeToSet) {
        type = typeToSet;
    }
    public static Message getServerLogoutMessage() {
        Message logoutMessage = new Message("Server");
        logoutMessage.setType(MessageTypes.SERVER_LOGOUT);
        return logoutMessage;
    }
    public static Message getServerLogoutMessage(String src) {
        Message logoutMessage = new Message(src);
        logoutMessage.setType(MessageTypes.SERVER_LOGOUT);
        return logoutMessage;
    }
    public static Message getUserLogoutMessage(String source) {
        Message logoutMessage = new Message(source);
        logoutMessage.setType(MessageTypes.USER_LOGOUT);
        return logoutMessage;
    }

    public static Message getUsersListMessage(String source) {
        Message usersMessage = new Message(source);
        usersMessage.setType(MessageTypes.USERSLIST);
        return usersMessage;
    }
    public static Message getDuplicateMessage() {
        Message msg = new Message("Server");
        msg.setType(MessageTypes.USER_DUPLICATE);
        return msg;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Source : " + getSrc() + "\n" + 
                "Dest : " + getDest() + "\n" +
                "Type : " + getType() + "\n" +
                "Content : " + getMessageContent() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Function at the server class:

```
public synchronized void handelMessage(Message msg) {
    ClientListenerWriterPair p;
    String src = msg.getSrc();
    String content = msg.getMessageContent();
    String toWrite;
    switch (msg.getType()) {
    case PTIVATE_MASSAGE:
        sendPrivateMessage(msg);
        break;
    case PUBLIC_MESSAGE:
        toWrite = String.format("%s : %s",src,content);
        control.writeTextToGui(toWrite);
        spreadTheMessage(msg);
        break;
    case USER_LOGOUT:
        p = nameToClientHash.remove(msg.getSrc());
        p.getListener().close();
        p.getWriter().close();
        p.getWriter().setMsg(Message.getUserLogoutMessage("Server"));
        try {
            p.getWriter().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        p.close();
        break;
    case SERVER_LOGOUT:
        p = nameToClientHash.remove(msg.getSrc());
        p.getListener().close();
        p.close();
        break;
    case USERSLIST:
        p = nameToClientHash.get(msg.getSrc());
        final Set<String> userSet = nameToClientHash.keySet();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Handling messages

> [...] I wish to refactor a couple of things, like the following `switch` statement that should be replaced with polymorphism or at least not rely on other class enum.

You could create `MessageHandler` classes that implement the actions in the current `case` statements,
and register them in a `MessageHandlerRegistry`,
that has a `Map<MessageType, MessageHandler>`.
And then,
as you process incoming `Message` instances,
you could get the `MessageHandler` from the `MessageHandlerRegistry` to perform the appropriate actions.
Something along the lines of:

```
  interface MessageHandler {
    void handle();
  }

  interface MessageHandlerRegistry {
    void register(MessageType type, MessageHandler handler);

    MessageHandler get(MessageType type);
  }

  // ...

  void processMessage(Message message) {
    messageHandlerRegistry.get(message.type()).handle();
  }
```

#### Creating `Message` instances

In `Message` you have several `static` methods that create messages, for example:

> ```
> public static Message getServerLogoutMessage() {
>     Message logoutMessage = new Message("Server");
>     logoutMessage.setType(MessageTypes.SERVER_LOGOUT);
>     return logoutMessage;
> }
> ```

Instead of naming these `getSomething` it would be better to name them `newSomething`, to indicate new instance creation.

But a bigger problem is that creating `Message` instances is a bit tedious,
due to the `setType` call that forces you to write 3 lines per message type.

It would be better to use the builder pattern,
so that you can create messages more fluently like this:

```
public static Message newServerLogoutMessage() {
    return builder().source("Server").type(MessageType.SERVER_LOGOUT).build();
}
```

And I would actually keep the `Message` class free from all this stuff,
and move these helper factory methods to a `Messages` class,
which is a common pattern, seen for example in the `Collections` class of the JDK.